# Where do the DotA All Stars and DOTA2 announcer voices come from? (Ownage, Unstoppable, etc.)

Tags: dota-2, dota

This is a question that has been bothering me since forever. I have tried to find the answer to no avail.

Back in the DotA days, and now DOTA2, I've heard those (hilarious) voices. I have read in several sources that the voice comes from the first **Unreal Tournament**, yet I don't recall hearing them in that game. In the next few games, the same words wre spoken, but never the same voice.

Searching through the internet, I have found several sites citing tha those are the original voices, but they are not the exact same voices of DotA. I have heard those voices in HL mods (such as CS or TFC)

Were those voices recorded specifically for DotA? If not, from what game? Any proof or investigation regarding that?

Comment: do you have a link of samples of some of those sounds? it very well could be the unreal tournament announcer (like the actor) just doing the accolades.

Comment: [This](http://unrealtournament.99.free.fr/utfiles/sound%20ut/dominating.wav) is an example. A list [here](http://unrealtournament.99.free.fr/utfiles/index.php?dir=sound%20ut/). I am looking for [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb7VuMhugiQ) voices.

Comment: Dota 1 Voices were definetly just taken from UT 99 - Dota 2 Voices were newly recorded because of higher quality Standards but in the same style.

Answer (score 1):

They're from the original Unreal Tournament.  The people who made Dota just used them and Valve kept them in for Dota 2 for nostalgia.

Comment: to expand upon this. Dota 1 is Unreal Tournament 99 voices. Dota 2 is Unreal Tournament 2k4.

Comment: According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwxjYFqP35A), the voices for UT99 aren't the same in DotA. DOTA2 have the same exact voices of DotA (yet of better quality, IMO), so they cannot be from different games, nor UT99 (if the video is correct, of course). The only one I did hear it was correct was "First blood"